# Almacenar datos en un stack C# desde Consola

Tags: c#, lista, hash, stack, colecciones

Buenas tengo una pequeña duda quien pueda ayudarme lo agradezco mucho, estoy intentando almacenar datos recibido por consola en una pila es decir Stack si entiende mejor esa palabra e imprimir esa lista luego que almacene todo lo el que usuario quiera seleccionar:

Esta es una parte del codigo pense que usar el metodo Push de la clase stack me almacena la informacion
recibida en la consola y con un switch intentar mostrar la informacion basado en el codigo que selecciono y se vayan almacenando en el stack hasta que acabe.

```
            foreach (var Articulos in listaArticulos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Codigo: {Articulos.code} ");

                Console.WriteLine($"Descripcion: {Articulos.descripcion} ");

                Console.WriteLine($"Precio: {Articulos.price} ");

                Console.WriteLine($"Categoria: {Articulos.categoria} ");

                Console.WriteLine($"Marca: {Articulos.marca}");
                Console.WriteLine("_________________");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("introduzca el codigo del articulo por favor");
            busqueda =int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

            carritoCompras1.Push(busqueda);
            foreach (var item in carritoCompras1)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: @EdgardoO Basicamente lo que quiero hacer que tome el codigo introducido por consola y de acuerdo al codigo vaya agregando el articulo asociado a ese codigo a la pila carriCompras1 y luego poder imprimr esa pila.

Comment: Podrías ayudarnos a proporcionar mas información al respecto, para muchos no nos queda claro lo que deseas realizar, si te sirve de algo revisa diversos post para redactar mejor tu pregunta
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que lo que te hace falta es buscar el código que se ingresó en la lista de todos los articulos y ese es el que vas a poner en la pila.  Puedes usar un Find para ver si existe ese código en la lista.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Articulos> listaArticulos = new List<Articulos>();
        int busqueda;
        Articulos articuloBusqueda = new Articulos();
        Stack<Articulos> carritoCompras1 = new  Stack<Articulos>();
        
        //listaArticulos = Llena los articulos de un json o db, por simplicidad pongo directo dos articulos
        Articulos articulo1 = new Articulos();
        articulo1.code = 100;
        articulo1.descripcion = "articulo código 100";
        listaArticulos.Add(articulo1);
        
        Articulos articulo2 = new Articulos();
        articulo2.code = 200;
        articulo2.descripcion = "articulo código 200";
        listaArticulos.Add(articulo2);
        //////////////////////////////
        
        
        /// se recorre la lista para mostrar todos en pantalla
        foreach (Articulos elemento in listaArticulos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Codigo: {0}", elemento.code);;
            Console.WriteLine("Descripcion: {0}", elemento.descripcion);
        }

        // solicita un código
        Console.WriteLine("introduzca el codigo del articulo por favor");
        busqueda =int.Parse (Console.ReadLine());
        
        /// el código se busca en la lista
        articuloBusqueda = listaArticulos.Find(x=>x.code == busqueda);
        
        // si existe el codigo se agrega  a la pila
        if(articuloBusqueda != null) {
            carritoCompras1.Push(articuloBusqueda);
        }
        
        /// se recorre la pila para imprimirla
        Console.WriteLine("Elementos en la pila");
        foreach (Articulos elemento in carritoCompras1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Codigo: {0} Descripcion: {1}", elemento.code, elemento.descripcion);
        }
    }
}

public class Articulos
{
    private int _code;
    private string _descripcion;
    
    public int code {get {return _code;} set { _code = value; }}
    public string descripcion {get {return _descripcion;} set { _descripcion = value; }}
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me diste una muy buena idea de lo que me hacia falta se agradece mucho bro.